# Facebook(workplace) Bot Post Permission v2.10 update

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot, facebook-workplace

I'm having a trouble in posting in a group using my chatbot.
the update in from v2.9 to v2.10 change the permission of groups that are closed and secret

```
Publishing

Permissions

For public Groups:
A User access token with the publish_actions permission.

For closed and secret Groups:
A Group admin's User access token with the publish_actions and user_managed_groups permissions.

link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/feed
```

my bot have a user_managed groups permission but I can't make my bot become an admin of a group and I cant add add it to a group.

ps. my bot can still post on public groups

questions: Is there another way that I can make my bot post again in close or secret groups?

Comment: since when can bots post to groups? i thought that they are for pages only?

Comment: _“questions: ”_ - answers: _already_ in the error message ...

Comment: @luschn in our workplace, specific for our company we don't have pages, it only composes of different groups for the business department, devs, heads, admins etc..

so we handle the questions that are not answerable by our bot by posting it to a group where the members are knowledgeable people that can answer it, sadly the group is closed one so since the update in v2.10 our bot cant post in the group

Comment: @CBroe but the error is forbidden request 403, when sending a post

Comment: Yeah, so what? The conditions under which you can still post, are mentioned in the message. And in the documentation as well. If what you are trying to do does not meet those criteria - then that is an answer as well.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the response :) Im still looking forward for another idea, you help me realize that (y)

Comment: Facebook has deliberately restricted this, to both protected user’s privacy better, and to help fight spam. Would not make much sense if they left any “loopholes” ... For closed/secret groups, you either have admin access to those groups, then you can post - or you don’t.

Comment: @CBroe but Im the creator of the group where the bot are posting and I make sure that my bot has all the access in editing/publishing in the group
this problem only show after the update from v2.10 - the problem now i see is i cant make a bot part of the group(make it a member) so that it can post to a secret/closed group

Comment: No, but you can supply it with the access token of a member that can post into the group ...

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! Like impersonating the bot would do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workplace developer team already fixed this issue few hours ago. The bots can again post to closed/secret group. Tested and working.

[image]